# Is there a way to override Firebase Remote Config's Region/Country

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I override the Locale of my Android App at startup and allow to change the region at runtime. 
I'm settings the Locale like this:

```
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
    }else{
        configuration.locale = locale;
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    res.updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```

Now i want to use Firebase-Remote-Config with a Region/Country Condition.
e.g.

```
test_property -> fr_FR = Bonjour 
              -> de_DE = Hallo
              -> default = Hi
```

If i now have my Device set to de_DE and my app set to `fr_FR` i will get the `test_property` from the `de_DE` region (`Hallo`). 
What i want to get is the `test_property` for the region `fr_FR` set by the app.

I tried to `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(...)` after changing the region in the app, but Firebase seems to get the region from somewhere else.

Does someone know a way to set/override the region programmatically so firebase will use that region for the region condition?

I don't want to use Firebase Analytics `User Properties`, as they get updated way too late.

Comment: >> "I don't want to use Firebase Analytics User Properties, as they get updated way too late."  Have you actually tried it? IIRC analytics user properties  should take affect immediately for the purpose of Firebase Remote Config condition resolution. Just make sure to get fresh configs from the servers, not from the app local cache.

Comment: Did you find a solution to override this value yet?

Answer (score 0):

In your **Firebase Console**:

a) Set a user property for locale. Go to `Analytics` menu and select `USER PROPERTIES` tab.

1. Provide user property name. Like `user_locale`.
2. Add description, save, and publish changes.

b) Set a condition for remote configs. Go to `Remote Config` menu and select `CONDITIONS` tab.

1. Select **User property** - `user_locale`.
2. Select `FOR TEXT` - `exactly matches`.
3. Put locale you need. Like `de` for German.
4. Put name like `translation_de` for condition and select a color.
5. Save and publish changes.

c) For every remote config parameter add value for condition.

1. From drop down menu select appropriate condition like `translation_de`.
2. Update and publish changes.

On locale change in your code set **User Property**

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getContext())
    .setUserProperty("user_locale", "de");
FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
    .fetch(1)
    .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().activateFetched();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is not the answer he is looking for.